# how to manage multiple android project using git branch

Tags: git

Now, I have one master project for develop, and there are many projects forked from it, my team uses git branch to manage this project, but it isn't convenient.

As you know, SVN can select which file or files to merge while merging two branches; can git achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVN and Git are based on different philosophies.

In Git, the repository is indivisible and you have to clone the whole repository every time (unlike `svn checkout`).

SVN repositories are more like independent sets of files and folders, sharing a common timeline only. This is how SVN deals with missing support for branches and tags – you can copy and merge parts of the repository.

As a result, a SVN repository tends to contain several projects, at least in my team. If it were to be converted to Git, these projects should be placed in separate repositories most likely (maybe connected using [`git submodule`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule)).

If you really need to perform merge of parts of the repository, there must be no changes in the rest. You can achieve it using the “commit-transplanting” commands (not present in SVN, by the way) like [`rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) or [`cherry-pick`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) before the merge.